# After changing the windows system time, the Date in the browser console is not updated immediately

Tags: windows-10, browser, javascript

After I changed the system date to '2024/2/27', the browser console still returns today's date. When I execute `new Date().toISOString()`, it returns `'2024-02-28T05:37:55.404Z'`. But after some time, it returns the correct date `'2024-02-27T05:38:53.711Z'`.

Why is `new Date()` in the browser not immediately synchronized to system time?

- OS: Windows 10
- Browser: Microsoft Edge 122.0.2365.52